# Run multiple files with vs code runner

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, vscode-code-runner

I want to compile and run multiple .cpp or .hpp files with Code Runner. Is this possible and if so, how?

Comment: Best way is to create a CMakeLists.txt and get the CMake Tools vscode extension.

Comment: It might be more helpful if you explain what you are trying to accomplish overall.

Comment: This seems the similar thing although it is golang: [vscode Code Runner cannot run multi go files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70859607/vscode-code-runner-cannot-run-multi-go-files)