# vscode Code Runner cannot run multi go files

Tags: go, visual-studio-code, vscode-code-runner

For example, I have a simple project called `demo`

```sh
demo
├── go.mod
├── main.go
└── sum.go
```

Here is the code, for `go.mod`, you can run `go mod init` under demo directory to generate automatically(but you can create in yourself to)

```golang
// main.go
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    num3 := sum(1, 2)
    fmt.Println(num3)
}

// sum.go
package main

func sum(num1 int, num2 int) int {
    return num1 + num2
}

// go.mod
module demo

go 1.17
```

Now in `main.go` file, right click mouse → Run Code, that means you will run main.go with Code Runner, but it will print an error

```sh
# command-line-arguments
demo/main.go:6:10: undefined: sum
```

The reason for this error is that Code Runner only runs the `main.go` file, if we `cd` to demo path in the Terminal and run `go run .`, the code can run very well.

How can we solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

If we want to run the code with Code Runner, we should add some config that can lets the Code Runner `cd` into the target folder and then run `go run .`.

open vscode setting page, click `view json` button on the top right corner
[image]

Add the following config to the json

```json
"code-runner.executorMap": {
    "go": "cd $dir && go run .",
},
"code-runner.executorMapByGlob": {
    "$dir/*.go": "go"
},
```

Be aware that the settings json may already have `"code-runner.executorMapByFileExtension"`, but this is not the same with `"code-runner.executorMap"`, do not add `"go": "cd $dir && go run .",` to `"code-runner.executorMapByFileExtension"`.

After adding the config, now you can run your go code with Code Runner, you don't need restart or reload vscode.